# Can you use @ instead of <% in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am seeing some examples online where the `@` is being used before server side code.

eg

```
<h2>Browsing Genre: @Model.Name</h2>
```

So can you just use a single `@` instead of wrapping the c#/vb code in `<% %>` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `@` if you're using the [Razor view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) in ASP.NET MVC.  That's most-likely what you're seeing examples of.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed razor syntax from MVC 3. Here is the syntax comparisons side by side
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Note @ html encodes *everything* by default unless whatever after the @ returns an MvcHtmlString.
<% %> in web forms did not html encode, but <%: %> syntax does.